# PHP Variable URL in a logo href

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to make a customization to the URL of a logo in Wordpress.
Basically the theme loads the logo with the base url. What i'm trying to achieve is making the URL change on every page based on the URL.
EXAMPLE:

http://www.website.com/one/two/three
What i need is only this part: http://www.website.com/one/

Then, I need to add it to href.
This is the code i have right now, that takes the base URL:

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
```

I tried using the "explode" to split the string into an array, but i'm not sure how to put it in the code above.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this, assuming you want just the first part of the path. This can be done with the server superglobals [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

The REQUEST_URI superglobal has the full path in it.

Given this url 'http://www.website.com/one/two/three'

### Code

```
$fullPath = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$firstPartOfThePath = fullPath[1];
echo('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $firstPartOfThePath);
```

This will create the url string 'http://www.website.com/one'

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! I ended up using this code and it works!

`<?php $variable = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$variable = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $variable[1] . '/';?>
      
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url($variable); ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using this code:

```
<?php$urllogovariabile = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urllogovariabile = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $urllogovariabile[1] . '/';?>

<a class="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url($urllogovariabile); ?>">
```